# How to use Matplotlib to plot curves with nonlinear x axis ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, curve, non-linear

Currently, I can use the following code to plot my data as two curves.

```
from numpy import *
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = [1,2,4,8] 
raw_1 = [0.02, 0.02, 0.3, 0.4] 
raw_2 = [0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3]
plt.plot(t, raw_1, color='r', marker='o') 
plt.plot(t, raw_2, color='b', marker='o')  
plt.show()
```

However, I hope to make the x-axis nonlinear. For example, only 1, 2, 4, 8 are visible and their x-ticks are separated with a same distance. As shown in this figure:[image]

I am not very familiar with Matplotlib, could someone please tell me how I can generate a plot with the above x-axis?

I tried plt.xscale('log'), but I got the following plot:
[image]

The distance between 2 adjacent nodes looks nice, but the xticks does not look well.

Comment: `plt.scale('log')` will set log scale distances.  See e.g. [Custom scientific axis unit for a bar plot with log scale x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302588/custom-scientific-axis-unit-for-a-bar-plot-with-log-scale-x-axis/64305540#64305540)

Comment: There are two ways to do so. 1. One can plot x-axis in the logarithmic scale. 2. One can use 1,2,4,8 as categorical variables. Which way do you think is more appropriate?

Comment: Please don't do `from numpy import *` but always `import numpy as np`.  You can get terribly weird behavior because numpy redefines some very common functions.

Comment: @kate-melnykova Is it possible to use 1,2,4,8 as categorical variables? I tried plt.xscale('log'), but the sticks look very strange.

Comment: Check answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090402/plot-number-like-categorical-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plot against arbitrary equally spaced numbers (it is convenient to use `range()`) for this, then replace the labels with your actual labels:

```
t = [1,2,4,8] 
raw_1 = [0.02, 0.02, 0.3, 0.4] 
raw_2 = [0.6, 0.7, 0.2, 0.3]
x = range(len(t))
plt.plot(x, raw_1, color='r', marker='o') 
plt.plot(x, raw_2, color='b', marker='o')
plt.xticks(x,t)
plt.show()
```

[image]